# adding new values to the pandas series

Tags: pandas

I make a Series from a list based on reading files. The Series is appended to csv file in each iteration. However, the column name is also appended every time. How can I avoid this issue?

```
 data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['min'])
 for i in range(int(Step)):
        two_min_batch = []
        for j in range(time_2min):
            two_min_batch.append(signal[j + i * time_2min])
        min.append(calculate_min(two_min_batch))

  data['min']= pd.Series(min)
  data.to_csv('./output/result.csv', index=False, mode='a')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the flag header=None in the to_csv function, it will not add headers while appending or when writing to a file.

```
data.to_csv('./output/result.csv', index=False, mode='a', header=None)
```